# TF global step update

Tags: python, tensorflow

Recently while reviewing an example training code I have encountered the following:

```py
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
gstep = tf.compat.v1.train.get_or_create_global_step()
lr = tf.cond(gstep < 100, lambda: base_lr, lambda: base_lr / 2.0)
```

I couldn't understand when `gstep` is updated. Is it updated every batch of data or every epoch?